# Code Signing Identity in XCode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, signing

I get this message when I start a build to my device in Xcode;
Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'vindfyrar2' could not be found

I've been through all the certificate/provisioning profile verification process.
I have valid provisionings profiles installed on my device in xcode organizer.
What I think is my problem is that I can't see any provisioning profiles in the target or project build settings -> code signing identity.

Take a look at the pictures below please!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu9M4.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Njf.png]

Anyone please have some time to help me?

Comment: Upload picture to [any third party site](http://tinypic.com/) and post the link here.

Comment: Aaah, here is my photos; [link](https://picasaweb.google.com/gifvars/XCodetrouble#5836578540470127554)   [link](https://picasaweb.google.com/gifvars/XCodetrouble#5836578546588414290)  and my familyalbum as well, enjoy! :-)

Comment: Upload to this site http://tinypic.com/

Comment: Sorry, the pictures are now public...

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I encounter this problem, I find that restarting Xcode and selecting a different provisioning profile in your project (not target) build settings will cause the list to refresh. If you see no profiles anywhere, download them again from your apple developer center and drag them into the Organizer's Provisioning Profiles pane.

Comment: @user338018 glad I could help you out. Please check my answer to signify it was the right one, cheers!

Comment: I don't think you understand the real bug. Xcode maintains a compiled repository. (like make in Linux). However, sometimes it doesn't realise changes in a particular file. Hence it won't compile the edited file. If you clean the repository and rebuild the project that should solve your problem. Restarting the Xcode, does rebuild the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

In the project build settings, set the Code Signing Identity to Automatic Profile Selector (iPhone Developer).  Now check that Code Signing menu again, it should say "(currently matches: iPhone Developer: Jan Gifvars (xxxx) in 'iOS Team Provisioning Profile:*)".  If it doesn't, you need to make sure you've got proper private key, certificate, and provisioning profiles.  Follow ALL the steps in this tech note.
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Comment: Thank you all for your time!